# python convert str to list

Tags: python, string

How do i convert

```
'[update, /CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1], Centaurus-AB]'
```

to a list  of strings, eg.

```
   ['update', '/CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1]', 'Centaurus-AB']
```

Comment: the input string is a well-defined format or custom?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without knowing more details about the input (do we really need to check if the brackets are there? commas are valid inside a field? ...) the simplest way probably is:

```
>>> [s.strip() for s in input_line[1:-1].split(',')]
['update', '/CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1]', 'Centaurus-AB']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
strings = '[update, /CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1], Centaurus-AB]'

strings = strings.replace("[", "").split(',')

print strings
```

EDIT:

oops. you want strip.. strip only takes first and last chars. Replace well remove all

```
strings = '[update, /CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1], Centaurus-AB]'

strings = strings.strip("[]", "").split(',')

print strings
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [12]: text='[update, /CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1], Centaurus-AB]'
In [17]: text[1:-1].split(',')
Out[17]: ['update', ' /CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1]', ' Centaurus-AB']
```

Note that using `text[1:-1]` relies on the string starting and ending with brackets (or, at least, some throw-away character).

To get rid of the whitespace you could use `strip()`:

```
In [18]: [elt.strip() for elt in text[1:-1].split(',')]
Out[18]: ['update', '/CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1]', 'Centaurus-AB']
```

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way to do this, but the first way I think of is:

```
>>> y = '[update, /CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1], Centaurus-AB]'
>>> y = y.split(',')
>>> y[0] = y[0].lstrip('[')
>>> y[-1] = y[-1].rstrip(']')
>>> y
['update', ' /CoaddedRegriddedFrame[1]/OBJECT[1]/text()[1]', ' Centaurus-AB']
```